# How to iteratively split a string using backward combinations?

Tags: python, list, split, combinations

I have a list of strings that look like this:

```
['C04.123.123.123', 'C03.456.456.456', 'C05.789.789.789']
```

I'm trying to split each string so I get different *backward* combinations of splits on the period delimiter. Basically, if I only take the example of the first string, I want to get:

```
['C04.123.123.123', 'C04.123.123', 'C04.123', 'C04']
```

How can I achieve this? I've tried looking into itertools.combinations and the standard split features but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-line, easy to understand (was less easy to tune :)), using `str.rsplit` with maxsplit gradually increasing up to the number of dots:

```
lst = ['C04.123.123.123', 'C03.456.456.456', 'C05.789.789.789']

result = [x.rsplit(".",i)[0] for x in lst for i in range(x.count(".")+1) ]
```

result:

```
['C04.123.123.123',
 'C04.123.123',
 'C04.123',
 'C04',
 'C03.456.456.456',
 'C03.456.456',
 'C03.456',
 'C03',
 'C05.789.789.789',
 'C05.789.789',
 'C05.789',
 'C05']
```

The only thing that annoys me is that it calls `split` a lot just to keep the first element. Too bad there isn't a built-in lazy `split` function we could call `next` on.

Comment: Think I'll go with this as it's cleaner to put in a lambda expression for pandas dataframes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
d = ['C04.123.123.123', 'C03.456.456.456', 'C05.789.789.789']
new_d = [a+('.' if i else '')+'.'.join(i) for a, *c in map(".".split, d) 
     for i in [c[:h] for h in range(len(c)+1)][::-1]]
```

Output:

```
['C04.123.123.123', 'C04.123.123', 'C04.123', 'C04', 'C03.456.456.456', 'C03.456.456', 'C03.456', 'C03', 'C05.789.789.789', 'C05.789.789', 'C05.789', 'C05']
```

Comment: `lambda x:x.split('.')` would be better as `".".split`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh right. Please see my recent edit

Answer (score 0):

```
start_list = ['C04.123.123.123', 'C03.456.456.456', 'C05.789.789.789']
final_list = []
for item in start_list:
   broke_up = item.split('.')
   temp = []
   full_item = []
   for sect in broke_up:
      temp.append(sect)
      full_item.append(".".join(temp))
   final_list.extend(full_item)
print(final_list)
```

Alternatively you can `final_list.append(full_item)` to keep seperate lists for each string in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list(accumulate(s.split('.'), lambda a, b: a + '.' + b))[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.accumulate`:

```
from itertools import accumulate
s = 'C04.123.123.123'
# define the incremental step
append = lambda s, e: s + '.' + e
result = list(accumulate(s.split('.'), append))[::-1]
```